# how to understand the proof of lemma 1.13 of Elliott Mendelson's book?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In the book Elliott Mendelson this lemma is used to prove the theorem of completeness, however, although I understand the lemma approach, I can not understand the reason for the different cases of the demonstration and the extra variables used.

[image: Lemma 1.13]

[image: Proof]

Comment: As it is a proof by induction, and a wf is, by inductive definition, a statement letter, or $\neg\mathscr C$ for some wf $\mathscr C$, or $(\mathscr C\Rightarrow\mathscr D)$ for some wfs $\mathscr C, \mathscr D$.

Comment: It means that, for a given truth-assignment $v: \{ B_1, \ldots, B_k \} \to \{ \text {TRUE }, \text { FALSE } \}$, where the $B_i$ are the statement letters occurring into the propositional formula $\mathcal B$, we can manufacture a derivation in the calculus as in the Lemma.

Comment: I understand very well that from B1,…,Bk can be deduced B if this is true or ¬B if this is false. However, the form of the demonstration is confusing for me, of all the cases I only understand the first, the others I do not understand.

Comment: I do not understand why the beginning is mentioned "the proof is by induction on the number n of occurrences of ¬ and →"

Answer (score 2):

Consider a couple of cases with the number of connectives $n=1$:

(A) $\mathcal B$ is $P \to P$. Here we have $i=1$ and $B_1=P$.

Consider a truth assignment $v$ such that $v(P)=$ TRUE. Thus, $B_1'=P$ and $\mathcal B' = \mathcal B$.

By "basic" case of the lemma, we have $P \vdash P$.

Thus, what we want is to "manufacture" a derivation: $P \vdash P \to P$.

We apply the subcase 2b; we have:

1) $P \vdash P$

2) $\vdash P \to (P \to P)$ --- axiom (A1)

3) $P \vdash P \to (P \to P)$ --- from 2)

> 4) $P \vdash P \to P$ --- from 1) and 3) by MP.

---

(B) $\mathcal B$ is $P \to Q$. Here we have $i=2$ and $B_1=P, B_2=Q$.

Consider a truth assignment $v$ such that $v(P)=$ TRUE and $v(Q)=$ FALSE.

Thus, $B_1'=P, B_2'= \lnot Q$ and $\mathcal B' = \lnot \mathcal B$, because for the said truth assignment $v: v(P \to Q)=$ FALSE.

Again by "basic" case of the lemma, we have $P \vdash P$ and $\lnot Q \vdash \lnot Q$ and we want: $P, \lnot Q \vdash \lnot (P \to \lnot Q)$.

We apply the subcase 2b; we have:

1) $P \vdash P$

2) $\lnot Q \vdash \lnot Q$

2) $\vdash P \to (\lnot Q \to \lnot (P \to Q))$ --- by Lemma 1.11(f)

> 3) $P, \lnot Q \vdash \lnot (P \to \lnot Q)$ --- from 1),2) and 3) by MP twice.

---

This is the "gist" of the induction proof: we have the "basic" building blocks (the case for the statement letters) and we have the induction step: the cases for the conncetives.

Using them, we have an algorithm for manufacturing the needed derivation.